# user uploaded images should be stored in the project like public/userprofileimage.jpg or it will be affected by version control

Tags: laravel, github, version-control, cdn

Consider the case where a user uploaded his profile image and it was placed in the project as public/userprofileimage.jpg when the repository was at version 1.0.0.

The project was then pulled from GitHub, changed, or new code was added, and it was pushed to the repository, becoming version 2.0.0.

How can I add the latest uploaded photos to the repository each time a user uploads something?

Will the user-uploaded picture be in 2.0.0?

or the image will be lost

What should I do with the user-uploaded images if that's the case so they don't get lost in version control?

```
  if($request->hasFile('image1') && $request->hasFile('image2') && $request->hasFile('image3') && $request->hasFile('image4')){
        $formFields['media'] = 
        $request->file('image1')->store('postUploads','public') . ',' 
        . $request->file('image2')->store('postUploads','public') . ',' 
        . $request->file('image3')->store('postUploads','public') . ',' 
        . $request->file('image4')->store('postUploads','public');
    }
```

and did that

```
php artisan storage:link
```

l retrieve the image like that

```
<img src="{{asset('storage/' . $image)}}" class="md:w-48 m-2 rounded" alt="">
```

is that the right way?

thanks

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: @jarlh is the question not clear ?

Comment: Far from clear. You mention some technologies and ideas, but do not show us any code, or tell us what the problem is.

Comment: @jarlh The issue isn't with the code; rather, it is whether a user's uploaded image would be lost if I make changes to the code on Github and push the updated repository to the hosting service.

Comment: @jarlh I revised the question in the hopes of making it clearer.

Comment: You should not store your user images in version controlled directories.

Instead use the Storage facade to keep it on local disc somewhere outside of version control, or better yet an external storage like an S3 bucket.

Comment: @Aziz, the images are not lost. If you cannot find them in Version 2.0, check your version control file ``.gitignore``. You might have excluded the directory from loading. Version control will not "lose" files. Just a configuration matter.

Comment: To add onto what @Gavin said, rather save your uploaded images in the Storage folder.... You can check Laravel documentation on filesystems. You will need to specify the disk you want to use, in your case "local" might be the way to go, although you have multiple options.

Comment: @Charles , please examine the question to see if it still captures what you both meant after I added the code.

Comment: I have removed the <sql> tag, since this isn't a SQL _language_ related issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

public function store(Request $request){

 $validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   $request->file('image1') => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
   $request->file('image2') => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
   $request->file('image3') => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
   $request->file('image4') => 'required|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg',
 ]);

if( $validate->fails() ){
 return response($validate->errors(), 400);
}

//anything below here means validation passed. You can then store your images

$path1 = $request->file('image1')->store('profile_pictures','public');
$path2 = $request->file('image2')->store('profile_pictures','public');
$path3 = $request->file('image3')->store('profile_pictures','public');
$path4 = $request->file('image4')->store('profile_pictures','public');

}
```

Note that this can even be further simplified by saving your images to an array. I did not use that approach as I am not sure whether all the images are profile images or will be used differently.

Your images will be stored in `/storage/profile_pictures` and Laravel will automatically generate an image name for you.

On your view you can call the images using the `asset` helper as below

```html
<img src="{{ asset($path1) }}"/>
```

This is assuming you are sending the image paths individually, which also can be simplified based on your application. Hope this give you an idea.

Comment: By using that method, I won't have to worry about the images not being in the github repository or stored in S3 bucket and it will not be lost?

Comment: The images will not be lost. Check a file called ``.gitignore``. In this file you specify the folders or files you do not want to load to your version control, for example ``node_modules`` folder. Just check if you did not add the current folder where your images are being stored to this folder. That's the only reason I can think of as to why your images are not uploading to version control.

Comment: many thanks You helped me understand the issue and improved my code. I hope you have a happy life.